# WooCommerce: Custom Template for Grouped / Bundled Products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I created a page using a combination of Woocommerce and Advanced Custom Fields ACF to achieve a product list with a very complex layout. Products might appear more than once but can only be bought once and other weird stuff. The products are pulled in using ACF `post objects` within a `repeater field`.

I also managed to display an add to cart button for each product using the `[products]` shortcode provided by woocommerce.

What I would love to have now is a an "Add all products to cart"-button to buy all products on this page instead of adding them to the cart individually.

I already tested woocommerce grouped and bundled products, but I need much more flexibility in terms of layout. The hooks provided to adjust the layout are not flexible enough.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use some jQuery. Have a custom button that when clicked it triggers the 'add to cart button' on all the products?

Something like

```
$('.addall').on('click', function() {
  $('.product').each(function(){
    $(".addToCart", this).trigger( "click" );
  });
});
```

[Simple fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oys1uf6a/) to show `trigger` working.

Comment: Thanks! I tested this on a regular product archive, because the shortcode implementation on my custom post seems to be faulty. Have to fix that first. Here is what happens on a product archive: the add-all button tries to load each individual product page which leads to a load frenzy that stops with loading the last product page. But nothing is added to the cart.

Comment: So to add an individual product, do you need to go to the product page first?

Comment: No it just adds a "view cart"-button under the individual product but stays on the archive page.

Comment: Fixed other code issues and your code works now! Thanks a lot!